# Transaction in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have two tables, `Order` and `Dish` and I need to create a transaction that ensure that the dishes will be insert in order at the same time. How can I apply a transaction here?

I've done this:

```
foreach($options as $name)
{
        $nomeA = $name;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Order VALUES ('$email',$nEnc,'$nomeA');";
        echo("<p>$sql</p>");
};
$tot_sql = "start transaction;".$sql."rollback;";
$db->query($tot_sql);
```

but I think it won't work because `$sql` will change and overwrite the previous query.

Comment: You're overwriting `$sql` each time through the loop, not appending them.

Comment: Use `.=` instead of `=`.

Comment: why someone downvote me? :/ what did i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.=` to append to a string:

```
$sql = '';

foreach ($options as $name) {
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Order VALUES ('$email', $nEnc, '$name');";
    echo "<p>$sql1</p>";
    $sql .= $sql1;
}

$tot_sql = "start transaction;".$sql."rollback;";
$db->query($tot_sql);
```

You could also do all the inserts in a single statement with multiple `VALUES` lists.

```
$values = array();
foreach($options as $name) {
    $values[] = "('$email', $nEnc, '$name')";
}
if (count($values)) {
    $values_string = implode(',', $values);
    $sql = "start transaction;INSERT INTO Order VALUES $values_string;rollback;";
    $db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: You could put transaction statements around it. I'm not sure if it's needed, a single statement may be done as a transaction automatically.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i will pick your first attempt cause it show transactions statement and that's what is suppose to do.. thanks again ;)

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use a transaction with the second version.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$sql='';
foreach($options as $name)
{
        $nomeA = $name;
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO Order VALUES ('$email',$nEnc,'$nomeA');";
        echo("<p>$sql</p>");

};
$tot_sql = "start transaction;".$sql."rollback;";
$db->query($tot_sql);
```

Comment: You'd have to make sure the engine in question supports multiple statements, too.

Answer (score 0):

Also Order is a reserved word,use backticks

```
`order`
```

Comment: i write order cause is the translation, actually is named "Encomenda"